# Update sql columns with true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, sql-update

I would like to update the columns Brand A, Brand B and Brand C with results of either "true" or "false", based on the **customer_code column** and the **Brand column**.

For example, table **market** shows the following:
 I have a customer who bought brand A and B:

```
Customer_code   Brand   Brand A Brand B Brand C
1234567            A    NULL    NULL    NULL
1234567            B    NULL    NULL    NULL


Customer_code   Brand   Brand A Brand B Brand C
1234567           A     True    True    False
1234567           B     True    True    False
```

As I have quite a large number of data so is there any way to solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried any queries before posting the question?

Comment: Yes! you can write simple sql update query.

Comment: What happens when you start selling a fourth brand? Are you going to add a new column to your table called "Brand D"? If so your design is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot or redundancy in storing data this way:

```
Customer_code   Brand   Brand A Brand B Brand C
1234567           A     True    True    False
1234567           B     True    True    False
```

The normal way to store this would simply be:

```
Customer_code   Brand 
1234567           A    
1234567           B
```

Since your true/false columns are based on the data in the first two, storing them is a bad idea since you then have the additional task of maintaining their accuracy.

Imagine I inserted a new row to your table, even if I insert it with the correct true/false values for each brand, it would still make the the first two rows wrong:

```
Customer_code   Brand   Brand A Brand B Brand C
1234567           A     True    True    False
1234567           B     True    True    False
1234567           C     True    True    True
```

As I have said, I would suggest only storing the customer_code and the brand, the rest can be calculated from these two columns. Finally, I would also suggest using the [BIT DataType](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) to represent boolean values, rather than storing true or false as text (there is no boolean type in SQL Server). So you can create a view:

```
SELECT  pvt.Customer_Code,
        [Brand A] = CAST(CASE WHEN pvt.[A] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT),
        [Brand B] = CAST(CASE WHEN pvt.[B] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT),
        [Brand C] = CAST(CASE WHEN pvt.[C] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM    (   SELECT  Customer_Code, Brand, Value = 1
            FROM    T
        ) T
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(Value)
            FOR Brand IN ([A], [B], [C])
        ) pvt;
```

This gives a result of:

```
Customer_code | Brand A | Brand B | Brand C
--------------+---------+---------+----------
1234567       |     1   |     1   |     0
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70a6e/4)**

It does not have the brand column, but this is redundant as the brand is implied by the bit column for each brand, so including the brand just causes duplicate rows.

Finally, to actually answer your question you can use the following to actually do your update:

```
WITH PVT AS
(   SELECT  Customer_Code, [A], [B], [C]
    FROM    (   SELECT  Customer_Code, Brand, Value = 1
                FROM    T
            ) T
            PIVOT
            (   COUNT(Value)
                FOR Brand IN ([A], [B], [C])
            ) pvt
)
MERGE T
USING PVT
    ON PVT.Customer_Code = T.Customer_Code
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET [Brand A] = CASE WHEN pvt.A > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
        [Brand B] = CASE WHEN pvt.B > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
        [Brand C] = CASE WHEN pvt.C > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bdd9/2)**

Or the SQL Servier Specific UPDATE/FROM syntax:

```
WITH PVT AS
(   SELECT  Customer_Code, [A], [B], [C]
    FROM    (   SELECT  Customer_Code, Brand, Value = 1
                FROM    T
            ) T
            PIVOT
            (   COUNT(Value)
                FOR Brand IN ([A], [B], [C])
            ) pvt
)
UPDATE  T
SET     [Brand A] = CASE WHEN pvt.A > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
        [Brand B] = CASE WHEN pvt.B > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
        [Brand C] = CASE WHEN pvt.C > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN PVT
            ON PVT.Customer_Code = T.Customer_Code;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bdd9/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE m
SET Brand_A = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Market m2
                               WHERE m.Customer_code = m2.Customer_code
                               AND   m2.Brand = 'A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Brand_B = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Market m2
                               WHERE m.Customer_code = m2.Customer_code
                               AND   m2.Brand = 'B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Brand_C = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Market m2
                               WHERE m.Customer_code = m2.Customer_code
                               AND   m2.Brand = 'C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.Market m
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de741/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
create table market
(customer_code varchar(200),
brand char(1),
brand_a int,
brand_b int,
brand_c int
);

insert into market values('1234567','A',0,0,0);
insert into market values('1234567','B',0,0,0);

UPDATE market
SET brand_a = a, brand_b = b, brand_c = c
FROM
(
 SELECT customer_code c_code,
 MAX(CASE WHEN brand = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) over(PARTITION by customer_code) a,
 MAX(CASE WHEN brand = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) over(PARTITION by customer_code) b,
 MAX(CASE WHEN brand = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) over(PARTITION by customer_code) c
 FROM market
) aa

WHERE customer_code = c_code;
```

Ther other thing is to remove not needed columns and just store customer and brand in the db and later just use the query:

```
    SELECT 
    customer_code,
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brand_a,
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brand_b,
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brand_c
    FROM market
    GROUP BY customer_code;
```